# Accessing request variable in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Im writing a simple application, where I can collect some information from a form and display it on the same template..

Below is the code,

When I try to access - `{{request.POST['fname']}}` - from the template , I get the following error,

```
Could not parse the remainder: '['fname']' from 'request.POST['fname']'
```

How do I access the request variable in the template?

```
views.py

    def test_page(request):
        print 'request.method =', request.method
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print 'request.post = ', request.POST['fname']
            variables = RequestContext(request,{'display_form':False})
            return render_to_response('test_page.html',variables)
        else:
            variables = RequestContext(request,{'display_form':True})
            return render_to_response('test_page.html',variables)

template

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    This is a test page
    {% if display_form %}
        <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            FIRST NAME : <input type="text" name="fname">
            <input type="submit" value="register"/>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        {{request.POST['fname']}}
    {% endif %}

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to get request.POST explicitly in template. Handling request.POST is more business logic related so controller/view should handle it.

Here is optimized code. There are less code duplication and it's more clear. fname is `None` if there are no first name specified. It's also better to use Django `Form` or `ModelForm` class to handle forms. Please check it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

You should also use `UTF-8` instead of `charset=ISO-8859-1" to have less problems with unicode characters later.`http-equiv`is a little bit outdated (it's used for HTML 4.01), use`meta charset` instead.

view:

```
def test_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        display_form = False
    else:
        fname = None
        display_form = True

    variables = RequestContext(request,{'display_form': display_form, 'fname': fname})
    return render_to_response('test_page.html', variables)
```

template:

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
This is a test page
{% if display_form %}
    <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        FIRST NAME : <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="register"/>
    </form>
{% else %}
    {{ fname }}
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the optimized solution you should instill best practices and issue a redirect.

Comment: You are right, but topic starter did not provided any reasons why he wants to have form like that. So, where it should be redirected by your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
{{ request.POST.fname }}
```

This will perform a lookup of `fname` in `request.POST`.

Django supports:

- dictionary lookups (`foo['bar']`)
- attribute lookups (`foo.bar`)
- list lookups (`foo[bar]`)

whenever you write `foo.bar` (see [Variables and lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) in the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to access a dictionary value in template is: `{{ request.POST.fname }}`

Answer (score 0):

First off you should index it via `request.POST.fname` it's a dictionary like object and also it always returns strings, just a FYI.

Secondly, after dealing with a `POST` request you should always issue a redirect (`HttpResponseRedirect`) and not a normal `render`. 
This will prevent data from being submitted twice if the user presses the back button.

This is best practice and should always be done.